# the remote name could not be resolved:'images.amazon.com'

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

In my asp.net web application i am using amazon plugin to load book images with corresponding isbn.in code behind i am converting that image into byte array for storing that into database.But the problem is it some times  come back with an error see picture
[image: Error message]

Can any specify the reason for this error and please suggest me some solutions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens when you reach the throttle limit.

try to wrap your code in try catch block

eg.

```
void withretry(string query)
{
    ListMatchingProductsRequest request = new ListMatchingProductsRequest();
    request.SellerId = amazonsetting.merchantId;
    request.MarketplaceId = amazonsetting.marketplaceId;
    request.QueryContextId = "Books";
    request.Query = query;
    try
    {
        ListMatchingProductsResponse response = amazonsetting.service.ListMatchingProducts(request);
        if (response.IsSetListMatchingProductsResult())
        {
            ListMatchingProductsResult listMatchingProductsResult = response.ListMatchingProductsResult;
            if (listMatchingProductsResult.IsSetProducts())
            {
                ProductList products = listMatchingProductsResult.Products;
                List<Product> productList = products.Product;
                Product product = productList[0];
                if (product.IsSetIdentifiers())
                {
                    IdentifierType identifiers = product.Identifiers;
                    if (identifiers.IsSetMarketplaceASIN())
                    {
                        ASINIdentifier marketplaceASIN = identifiers.MarketplaceASIN;
                        if (marketplaceASIN.IsSetMarketplaceId())
                        {
                        }
                        if (marketplaceASIN.IsSetASIN())
                        {
                            asin = marketplaceASIN.ASIN;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (product.IsSetAttributeSets())
                {
                    foreach (var attribute in product.AttributeSets.Any)
                    {
                        msg += ProductsUtil.FormatXml((System.Xml.XmlElement)attribute);
                    }
                }

            }
            parsemsg();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string type = ex.Message;
        if (type=="Request is throttled")
        {
            if (cnt<=maxretry)
            {
                cnt++;
                withretry(query);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

this will keep on retrying until maxretry is reached.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.i will try and let you know the result.